# With Git-Mediawiki, how to access a Mediawiki site in a directory protected with .htpasswd?

Tags: git, apache, mediawiki, password-protection, .htpasswd

I am using [Git-MediaWiki](https://github.com/moy/Git-Mediawiki/wiki) to access a remote Mediawiki site via Git.  But the wiki site's root directory is password protected with [htpassword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htpasswd).  So naively using `git fetch` does not work:

```
git fetch origin
Password for 'http://adminuser0@example.com': 
Failed to log in mediawiki user "adminuser" on http://example.com/mywiki
  (error 2: 401 Authorization Required : error occurred when accessing http://example.com/mywiki/api.php after 1 attempt(s))
fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: mediawiki::http://example.com/mywiki did not send all necessary objects
```

Following Git-Mediawiki's user manual, I have configuration in `localrepo/.git/config` as

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = mediawiki::http://example.com/mywiki
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    mwLogin = adminuser
```

Any idea? I was hoping if an scripted intermediate step could be inserted to enter the user name and password for the htpasswd protection.